# how can i retrieve the json data from url and store it in an array..?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, windows-phone-8

i'm working for windows phone 8.. 
i need to retrieve the Json data from url and i need to display in an array..

 my url have this jsondata like this..

```
 {       id: 9
            address: "abc"
            city: " chennai"
            contact1: ""
            contact2: ""
            country: " india"
            description: ""
}
```

i would like to know how to retrieve this data and store it in an array?

here is the statements i used to retrieve the Json data.

```
private string REST_URL = "my url"; //i'm using my url here to extract the json data..

    String servicePath = REST_URL + "/data/" + query;            
    Detail[] detail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Detail[]>(servicePath);
    return detail;
```

my complete Json data

```
[
  {
    "id": 01,
    "address": "12asdf",
    "city": " chennai",
    "contact1": "",
    "contact2": "",
    "country": " india",
    "description": "",
    "name": " david",
    "region": "",
    "state": "  033",
    "website": "",
    "image": "",
     "PrayerTime": {
      "id": 01,
      "PrayerTime1": "00:52",
      "PrayerTime2": "21:04",
      "PrayerTime3": "12:27",
      "PrayerTime4": "05:35",
      "PrayerTime5": "21:04",
      "created_at": null,
      "PrayerTime6": "04:01",
      "updated_at": null,
      "organization_id": 001
    }
  },.............
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem are you facing? The JSON you post is not an array but a single object.

Comment: i need to store it into an array...so how can i do it..? or else help me to retrieve json data from url and to display it..

Comment: Can you post whole JSON? If the JSON in question is correct then use only `Detail` rather than `Detail[]`.

Comment: i had updated my complete Json data..

Comment: private string REST_URL = "my uri";  here i use my url to retrive the data

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: It seems your JSON might be wrong. Use http://json2csharp.com/ to create class from JSON.

Comment: i created my class using your reference website http://json2csharp.com/ -- only

Comment: please post class definition. I tried with your sample JSON it worked for me.

Comment: sry...i removed my post method code...i got problem in GetResponse().. can you please share your method to retrieve Json data.....

Comment: I used static JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that your model is correct. As @Xyroid stated use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/), which allows you to simply copy and paste your json and it will generate the corresponding c# code.

You can't give the URL to your parser, you will first have to download the JSON as string. To download the string simply use the [HttpClient](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) which you can even use in a [PCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
string jsonData = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```